# How do I fix the pyautogui's locateOnScreen not finding anything?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Here is the code,

```
import pyautogui
import time

while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("something.png", region=(0,400,575,400), confidence =0.6 )  != None:
        print(" I see")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        print("Me no see")
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

It just prints "Me no see" over and over no matter how much I try. I have tried putting the confidence to 0.5 but that just prints "I see".

Comment: Are you sure the image is found within the bounds specified by `region` (0<x<575, 400<y<800)?

Comment: I'm unsure as it also does not work without a region.

Comment: Maybe search region `0,0,2000,2000`.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work. I'm new to programming so I don't know if this is relevant, but, I am on MacOS.

Comment: I may have figured something out. The pictures that I have used may not have been exactly the same size as the comparison. Does anyone know how to still locate a smaller version of the png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a great documentation about [Screenshot Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#screenshot-functions) for `pyautogui`.

The `confidence` argument is optional and must have `OpenCV` to work.
The `region` argument is also optional, you can remove and the image will be still found.
You can use the argument `grayscale=True` if you want. As doc says: `This desaturates the color from the images and screenshots, speeding up the locating but potentially causing false-positive matches`.

The only not optional argument is the image, which needs to be a `.png` extension.
You also need to provide the image taken from the same resolution and scale took from the screen.

Suppose you are providing the image `something.png` that has been taken from a browser with `150%` zoom, and also searching this image from a `100%` zoom, it **won't** find the image no matter the arguments you are using it!

**So remember to save the images again in order to find them!**

```
import pyautogui

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("something.png", grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
    print("I see")
```

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, is there an easy way to resize the image? I have many photos that are of the wrong size so it would be a dreadful task changing them all to exactly fit the resolution.

Comment: Not that I know, because the pixels would change as well. But either way, that would be a different question on SO. If you find this answer helpful, don't forget to mark as accept please.